# Why does the **kwargs mapping compare equal with a differently ordered OrderedDict?

Tags: python, function, python-3.6, ordereddictionary, keyword-argument

According to [PEP 468](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0468/):

> Starting in version 3.6 Python will preserve the order of keyword arguments as passed to a function. To accomplish this the collected **kwargs will now be an ordered mapping**. Note that this does not necessarily mean `OrderedDict`.

In that case, why does this ordered mapping fail to respect equality comparison with Python's canonical ordered mapping type, the `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> data = OrderedDict(zip('xy', 'xy'))
>>> def foo(**kwargs):
...     return kwargs == data
... 
>>> foo(x='x', y='y')  # expected result: True
True
>>> foo(y='y', x='x')  # expected result: False
True
```

Although iteration order is now preserved, `kwargs` seems to be behaving just like a normal dict for the comparisons. Python has a C implemented ordered dict [since 3.5](https://bugs.python.org/issue16991), so it could conceivably have been used directly (or, if performance was still a concern, a faster implementation using a thin subclass of the 3.6 compact dict).

**Why doesn't the ordered mapping received by a function respect ordering in equality comparisons?**

Comment: What about the part that says "*Note that this does not necessarily mean `OrderedDict`*"?

Comment: Yes, what about it?

Comment: So you are comparing it to `OrderedDict`, maybe, that's not what is meant by "ordered mapping"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to your first 'why' is because this feature is implemented by using a plain `dict` in CPython. As @Ryan's answer points out, this means that comparisons won't be order-sensitive.

The second 'why' here is why this doesn't use an `OrderedDict`.

Using an `OrderedDict` was the initial plan as stated in the [first draft](https://github.com/python/peps/commit/c7a4a5842f56fbbc179dae567d225fa6b5038bb9#diff-ad534f0374d5a1f27d0657692ef27d77R180) of PEP 486. The idea, as stated [in this reply](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2014-April/027518.html), was to collect some perf data to show the effect of plugging in the `OrderedDict` since this was a point of contention when the idea was floated around before. The author of the PEP even alluded to the order preserving dict being another option in the [final reply](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2014-April/027477.html) on that thread.

After that, the conversation on the topic seems to have died down until Python 3.6 came along. When the new dict came, it had the nice side-effect of just implementing PEP 486 out of the box (as [this Python-dev thread states](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2016-September/146327.html)). The specific message in that thread also states how the author wanted the term `OrderedDict` to be changed to Ordered Mapping. (This is also when a [new commit on PEP 468](https://github.com/python/peps/commit/9cf9ffb58722c6cbed6d2ed297fb173795798773#diff-ad534f0374d5a1f27d0657692ef27d77L180), after the initial one, was made)

As far as I can tell, this rewording was done in order to allow other implementations to provide this feature as they see fit. CPython and PyPy already had a dict that easily implemented PEP 468, other implementations might opt for an `OrderedDict`, others could go for another form of an ordered mapping.

That does open the door for a problem, though. It does mean that, theoretically, in an implementation of Python 3.6 with an `OrderedDict` as the structure implementing this feature, the comparison would be order-sensitive while in others (CPython) it wouldn't. (In Python 3.7, all `dict`s are required to be insertion-ordered so this point is probably moot since all implementations would use it for `**kwargs`)

Though it does seem like an issue, it really isn't. As @user2357112 pointed out, there's no guarantee on `==`. PEP 468 *only* guarantees order. As far as I can tell, `==` is basically implementation defined.

---

In short, it compares equal *in CPython* because `kwargs` in CPython is a `dict` and it's a `dict` because after `3.6` the whole thing just worked.

Comment: Great finds Jim, this seems to be the correct answer (particularly [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2016-September/146327.html) part). The **kwargs iteration order was a "happy accident" of other developments in the dict type.  So, they dusted off the PEP 486 and accepted it, but that was more or less a side effect of compact dict impl.  I do think they could have re-worded the PEP more carefully, because any "ordered mapping" worth its salt should likely have the ordering considered by eq comparisons.

Comment: i.e., the 3.6 dict is not an ordered mapping, it's just a mapping that happens to preserve insertion order.

Comment: @wim The PEP is probably not as fleshed out as you would expect since it didn't go through the usual Python-dev iterations other PEPs go through. Also, yes, it isn't ordered in the sense that `OrderedDict` is defined to be. Using "ordered" is misleading but "marketing" I guess. I'll guess I need to clarify that in a couple of my answers.

Answer (score 14):

Regardless of what an “ordered mapping” means, as long as it’s not necessarily `OrderedDict`, `OrderedDict`’s `==` won’t take into account its order. [Docs:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects)

> Equality tests between `OrderedDict` objects are order-sensitive and are implemented as `list(od1.items())==list(od2.items())`. **Equality tests between `OrderedDict` objects and other `Mapping` objects are order-insensitive like regular dictionaries.** This allows `OrderedDict` objects to be substituted anywhere a regular dictionary is used.

Comment: 3.6 dict order is implementation detail, but the `kwargs` object received by a function being an ordered mapping is not an implementation detail.  So it should have correct equality comparisons with other ordered mappings, shouldn't it?

Comment: @wim: Added some parentheses.

Comment: @wim Regarding you equality operator, you cannot do what you want without violating the "transitive" requirement of the equals operator. That is, if `dict0 == ordered_dict0` and `dict0 == ordered_dict1`, then it must necessarily be that `ordered_dict0 == ordered_dict1`. With what you are suggesting this might not always be the case.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of the question.  The claim in the PEP is that "kwargs is an ordered mapping" but the implementation seems to be something weaker, something more like "the kwargs will preserve iteration order".

Comment: @Dunes  Transitivity is already broken (`OrderedDict([(1,2), (3,4)]) == {1:2, 3:4} == OrderedDict([(3,4), (1,2)])`), so who cares?

Comment: @Ryan I still don't think it's really answering the question, this is just restating what the behaviour **is**.  The CPython devs were surely aware there was a design choice to make here, and took this decision intentionally.  I'm looking for the reason(s).

Comment: @wim: It's showing that the behaviour is documented. I don't think you have a strong case for expecting the comparison to take order into account.

Comment: @Ryan  It is **not even showing that the behaviour is documented**, strictly speaking.  I put `return kwargs == data`, not `return data == kwargs`, which means that the "ordered mapping" has the first responsibility of handling the comparison, so how `OrderedDict.__eq__` is implemented is immaterial here.  It happens that `OrderedDict` is a subclass of `dict`, and `kwargs` *is a* `dict`, so the implementation of `OrderedDict.__eq__` is taken into account, but there is no reason it had to be done this way.

Answer (score 10):

"Ordered mapping" only means the mapping has to preserve order. It doesn't mean that order has to be part of the mapping's `==` relation.

The purpose of PEP 468 is just to preserve the ordering information. Having order be part of `==` would produce backward incompatibility without any real benefit to any of the use cases that motivated PEP 468. Using `OrderedDict` would also be more expensive (since `OrderedDict` still maintains its own separate linked list to track order, and it can't abandon that linked list without sacrificing big-O efficiency in `popitem` and `move_to_end`).

Comment: 1. I'm not convinced on the idea that changing `==` here would have to be more expensive (though using `OrderedDict` itself would be more expensive, yes).  For example, the compact dict impl improved performance along with preserved order.  2. What backwards incompatibility would have been produced, that was not a bug in the first place?  Changing this would not effect comparisons against other dicts, only against other ordered mappings.

Comment: @wim: 1) Changing `==` for *all* dicts would break an absurd amount of code for no practical reason, and making a new dict subclass just to have order be part of `==` would add complexity for no real benefit, as well as introducing interoperability issues with OrderedDict. 2) Any code relying on the old definition of `==` would break. Relying on the definition of `==` isn't a bug. Also, C code that uses PyDict_Whatever to access keyword argument dicts would need to be reexamined if keyword arguments come in a dict subclass or other mapping type.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, if you do want to make this check (without relying on an implementation detail (which even then, won't be in python 3.7)), just do

```
from collections import OrderedDict
>>> data = OrderedDict(zip('xy', 'xy'))
>>> def foo(**kwargs):
...     return OrderedDict(kwargs) == data
```

since this is guaranteed to be True.

Comment: I'm aware of the workaround, but why is that necessary in the first place since *kwargs will now be an ordered mapping*?

Comment: This returns `False` for both `foo(y='y', x='x')` and `foo(x='x', y='y')`

Comment: @smac89 does it? `foo(x='x', y='y')` gives me `True`. Are you not running python 3.6, or is this something whereby `OrderedDict` doesn't add `dict` elements in order?

Comment: @FHTMitchell, I think I was running 3.5 when I tested that. I will install 3.6 and check

Comment: @wim Because the `dict` equality operator does not care about order. Just because order is preserved, there is no guarantee that equality operators take this into account.

Comment: @FHTMitchell  But there is no guarantee that `kwargs` has to be a `dict`, and so use the dict equality methods, either.  It could easily be a thin subclass of dict that overrides `__eq__`.

Comment: I'm not sure of the usefulness of this answer in a "Why" question. Seems more suitable as a comment, really.

Comment: That would be a terrible idea that breaks backward compatibility. Again "guarantees order preservation" makes no comment as to whether an equality test takes it into account.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard because it shows that it is doable quickly and simply, so part of the answer "why" is because it wasn't considered necessary since the solution to this particular problem is easy.