# Will OrderedDict become redundant in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.7, ordereddict

From the [Python 3.7 changelog](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html):

> the insertion-order preservation nature of [dict](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) objects [has been declared](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html) to be an official part of the Python language spec.

Would this mean that [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) will become redundant? The only use I can think of it will be to maintain backwards compatibility with older versions of Python which don't preserve insertion-order for normal dictionaries.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34305003/difference-between-dictionary-and-ordereddict-in-python

Answer (score 201, accepted):

No it won't become redundant in Python 3.7 because `OrderedDict` is not just a `dict` that retains insertion order, it also offers an order dependent method, [`OrderedDict.move_to_end()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.move_to_end), and supports [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#reversed) iteration*.

Moreover, equality comparisons with `OrderedDict` are order sensitive and this is still not the case for `dict` in Python 3.7, for example:

```
>>> OrderedDict([(1,1), (2,2)]) == OrderedDict([(2,2), (1,1)]) 
False
>>> dict([(1,1), (2,2)]) == dict([(2,2), (1,1)]) 
True
```

Two relevant questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49159238/why-does-the-kwargs-mapping-compare-equal-with-a-differently-ordered-ordereddi).

* Support for `reversed()` iteration of regular Python `dict` is added for Python 3.8, see [issue33462](https://bugs.python.org/issue33462)

Comment: The point about order sensitivity when comparing is very valid here.

Comment: @leggewie In Python 3.8 (and in 3.9), the point about equality comparisons is still different between `OrderedDict` and regular `dict`- I do not expect this to change anytime soon