# Maintain insertion order when merging Python dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, merge

I read that Python 3.6+ maintains dictionary insertion order. If I merge 2 python dictionaries:

```
x = {"a":5, "d":3}
y = {"c":1, "b":2}
z = x | y
```

Does this ensure that the items in z are in the exact insertion order, i.e. z would now be

```
{"a":5, "d":3, "c":1, "b":2}
```

If not, how can I get my desired z?

Comment: Did you try merging the two dictionaries and seeing what the result was?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression (taking union of dictionaries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-taking-union-of-dictiona)

Comment: Is there a reason you're bothered about the insertion order at all? dictionaries arent designed to be sorted. `OrderedDict` may be better for you

Comment: @Kemp yes, just want to make sure it's generalizable.

Comment: @queste this other question doesn't address the order of the resulting dictionary.

Comment: @Sayse see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50872498/will-ordereddict-become-redundant-in-python-3-7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, it ensures insertion order**

The PEP which introduced this syntax, [PEP 584](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/), lays out the behaviour of the operator, with an example implementation that shows its semantics:

```
def __or__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, dict):
        return NotImplemented
    new = dict(self)
    new.update(other)
    return new
```

Since the introduction of insertion-ordered dictionaries, `dict.update` has been specified to keep the insertion order of its arguments, and thus `x | y` where `x` and `y` are dictionaries does too.