Reorder dict with custom order
Given a dict d, now that we know since Python 3.7 that (insertion) order is preserved, is there a built-in way to ask for the same dict with the same keys, except that some keys k1, k2, ... should come first?
Example:

key a (if present) should be first,
key first (if present) should be present next

I came up with this:
def reorder_dict(d, first_keys):
    new_keys = [k for k in first_keys if k in d.keys()] + [k for k in d.keys() if k not in first_keys]
    new_d = {k: d[k] for k in new_keys}
    return new_d

d1 = {"c": 3, "b": 2, "a": 1}
reorder_dict(d1, ["a", "first"])    # {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2} as expected ; NB: "first" is not present

Is there a built-in way to do this more directly?

Do you want to mutate an existing dict, or create a new one? How big is len(first_keys) compared to len(d)? What percentage of first_keys are expected to be missing from d?  (I am not the downvoter)

I think your initial approach is good, but it could be improved with a small adjustment. The if k not in first_keys part makes your code quadratic.
That inefficiency can be avoided:
def reorder_dict(d, first_keys):
    result = {k: d[k] for k in first_keys if k in d}
    result.update(d)
    return result

In Python 3.9+ a one-liner is possible using a dict union operator
>>> d = {"c": 3, "b": 2, "a": 1}
>>> first_keys = ["a", "first"]
>>> {k: d[k] for k in first_keys if k in d} | d
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}


first isn't a key in the original dictionary, and shouldn't be in the result. That's in the OP's example to show that the solution shouldn't add any new keys.

The keys that are listed in the ordering parameter have to be in the same order as that parameter. Your code doesn't ensure that. It puts them all at the front, but in the order that they were in the original dictionary, not in the order of the parameter.

@Barmar I don't understand what you're trying to say. I reread the question and this result seems correct, it doesn't add any new keys to the dict.

I thought dict.fromkeys(["first", "b", "a"]) was part of the solution, not creating the input data.

Your function still doesn't ensure that the keys in the result are in the same order as first_keys.

It's partitioning the dictionary, but not ordering it.

@Barmar I still don't understand what you're saying. Can you provide a counter-example?

reorder_dict({'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}, ['c', 'a']) should return {'c': 3, 'a': 1, 'b': 2}

@Barmar And it does. Show me a counter-example for which this code doesn't work.

@Basj  first is not hardcoded into the function.  What are you talking about?

You're right, it works. I didn't fully grasp what tuple(v != x for v in first_keys) was doing. An explanation of the algorithm would go a long way -- if an expert like me doesn't see it, what hope is there for the novices?

@Barmar Ok, I've removed the tuple keying example entirely.

@wim I spoke about an earlier edit when "first" was in the condition, my comment is no longer useful, I deleted it! PS: could you re-include the tuple(...) version? I always like to learn new ways to do it :) Thanks for your answer!

PS: why is lookup = dict.fromkeys(first_keys) needed, wouldn't it work if lookup = first_keys?

@Basj That's because lookup in dict is O(1) but lookup in list is O(n). I won't re-include the technique with a tuple keying because it's inferior, and confused even self-proclaimed "experts". But you can always view it in the revision history: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78342346/3

@wim Yes about O(1) lookup, but doing dict.fromkeys(first_keys), creating a dict from the original list takes O(n) anyway. Oh I see, do you do this to speed up the line result.update({... if k not in lookup})?

@Basj Yes, that was the idea, but now that you mention it, it's not actually required in the first place. Edited my answer.

Yes, you can achieve this using the OrderedDict class from the collections module. You can create a new OrderedDict where you specify the order of keys explicitly, ensuring that specific keys come first. Here's an example:
from collections import OrderedDict

# Your original dictionary

d = {'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'a': 1, 'first': 0}

# Define the order of keys

desired_order = ['a', 'first']

# Create a new OrderedDict with the desired order

ordered_d = OrderedDict((key, d[key]) for key in desired_order if key in d)

# Add remaining keys in their original order
for key in d:
    if key not in ordered_d:
        ordered_d[key] = d[key]

print(ordered_d)


You don't need OrderedDict for this. Since 3.8 Python dictionaries have been required to preserve insertion order.

How is this significantly different from what the OP wrote?

This @Barmar questions the following (off-topic) point: since Python 3.8, are there still (many) use cases for OrderedDict ?

In your example, @HammerChi, you should remove first key from d: this was done on purpose: the function should not bug if first is in desired_order but not in d (this case can happen).

@Basj I didn't say it's not needed for anything, just not needed for this.

Yes sure @Barmar, I understood this. But this made me think abut this offtopic point: is OrderedDict still useful since 3.8, and if so, what for?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50872498/will-ordereddict-become-redundant-in-python-3-7

As Barmar already mentioned, I'm not sure how this improves OP's existing code at all or what the point of using an OrderedDict was, it doesn't seem to use any of OrderedDict's features.
